# Ionic not loading view linked to tab on first click

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, angular-ui-router

The first page that loads in my ionic app is a welcome screen with two tabs that link to a 'log in' page and a 'sign up' page.  Upon first loading the app the first tab is already highlighted, and when I click that tab it does not load the corresponding page.  However, I am able to click the 2nd tab which loads the proper page as expected and after navigating back to the original view I am then able to select the 1st tab which loads it's corresponding page as expected.  I've been racking my brain and searching until head banging frustration.  I'm still very new to angularjs, javascript, and the MVC.  If someone is able to enlighten me as to what I'm doing incorrectly you guidance will be greatly appreciated. Here is a link to my codepen for the html of my welcome screen and my app.js file containing my routes.

In my searching i've seen similar issues with references to using state.go and ui-sref but i've only become more lost and confused while trying to understand how to implement the possible solutions to my situation.

```
<ion-view view-title="Login" hide-nav-bar="true">
 <ion-content class="padding splash">
 </ion-content>
</ion-view>

<ion-tabs class="tabs-dark" ng-app='starter"'>
 <ion-tab title="Log in" href="#/loginScreen"></ion-tab>
 <ion-tab title="Sign up" href="#/signUpScreen"></ion-tab>
</ion-tabs>
```

and the js code:

```
    angular.module('starter', ['ionic', 'starter.controllers', 'starter.services', 'firebase'])

.run(function($ionicPlatform) {
  $ionicPlatform.ready(function() {
    // Hide the accessory bar by default (remove this to show the accessory bar above the keyboard
    // for form inputs)
    if (window.cordova && window.cordova.plugins && window.cordova.plugins.Keyboard) {
      cordova.plugins.Keyboard.hideKeyboardAccessoryBar(true);
      cordova.plugins.Keyboard.disableScroll(true);

    }
    if (window.StatusBar) {
      // org.apache.cordova.statusbar required
      StatusBar.styleLightContent();
    }
  });
})

.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {

  // Ionic uses AngularUI Router which uses the concept of states
  // Learn more here: https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router
  // Set up the various states which the app can be in.
  // Each state's controller can be found in controllers.js
  $stateProvider

  // setup an abstract state for the tabs directive
    .state('tab', {
    url: '/tab',
    abstract: true,
    templateUrl: 'templates/tabs.html'
  })

  // Each tab has its own nav history stack:

  .state('tab.dash', {
    url: '/dash',
    views: {
      'tab-dash': {
        templateUrl: 'templates/tab-dash.html',
        controller: 'DashCtrl'
      }
    }
  })
  .state('tab.profile', {
    url: '/profile',
    views: {
      'tab-profile': {
        templateUrl: 'templates/tab-profile.html',
        controller: 'ProfileCtrl'
      }
    }
  })
  .state('tab.chats', {
      url: '/chats',
      views: {
        'tab-chats': {
          templateUrl: 'templates/tab-chats.html',
          controller: 'ChatsCtrl'
        }
      }
    })
    .state('tab.chat-detail', {
      url: '/chats/:chatId',
      views: {
        'tab-chats': {
          templateUrl: 'templates/chat-detail.html',
          controller: 'ChatDetailCtrl'
        }
      }
    })

    .state('login', {
      url: '/login',
          templateUrl: 'templates/login.html',
          controller: 'LoginCtrl'
  })

    .state('loginScreen', {
      url: '/loginScreen',
      templateUrl: 'templates/loginScreen.html',
      controller: 'LoginScreenCtrl'
    })

    .state('signup', {
      url: '/signUpScreen',
      templateUrl: 'templates/signUpScreen.html',
      controller: 'SignupCtrl'
  })


  .state('tab.account', {
    url: '/account',
    views: {
      'tab-account': {
        templateUrl: 'templates/tab-account.html',
        controller: 'AccountCtrl'
      }
    }
  });

  // if none of the above states are matched, use this as the fallback
  $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/login');

});
```

See the Pen LpGXJg by Grant Desselle (@floodzonestudios) on CodePen.

Comment: Have a look at your states. you dont seem to be providing views for the for the tabs. have a look at how your other states are formatted and maybe use a similar approach? i.e. add a tab view like `tab-login` and tab-signup